# Do I need special Type of crossover cable to connect two Gigabyte Ethernet controller?

Tags: networking, motherboard, ethernet, home-networking

I have two S1200V3RPS motherboards, each having two Gigabyte Ethernet controller. One connector in each motherboard is used to connect directly to internet. Now, I want to use second controller in each motherboard to connect with each other. What special kind of crossover cable do I need?

From the manual of my motherboard (http://www.manualslib.com/manual/708923/Intel-S1200v3rp.html?page=39#manual), I have Ethernet Controller I120. Now as per the manual of I120(http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/embedded/products/networking/i210-ethernet-controller-datasheet.html), it does appear that it is new Ethernet controller which support automatic crossover which supports straight LAN wire to connect between two PCs. But what confuses me is the following article on Windows Help :

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/connect-two-computers-crossover-cable#1TC=windows-7

It mentions in the note :

```
For Gigabit Ethernet or token ring networks, you will need a slightly different kind of crossover cable. For more information, contact a cable manufacturer.
```

Since I have Gigabit Ethernet controller, what slightly different kind of crossover cable do I need?

Comment: They actually talk about Token Ring still... But they do say "Before buying a crossover cable, check your network adapter. Some newer network adapters automatically cross over when they detect that they're connected directly to another network adapter using a regular Ethernet cable." Just try a normal cable that works with GE, it should be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need *any* crossover cable. [Auto-MDIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium-dependent_interface#Auto_MDI-X) is, as far as I know, a required part of Gigabit Ethernet specification and automatically negotiates normal/crossover usage over regular cables. (It's frequently implemented by 100 Mbps "Fast Ethernet" devices, too.)